# How can I extract customers who have transacted since a specific date? (active customers definition)

Tags: mysql, sql

All,

My definition of an **active** client is anyone who has transacted since November 2019. I am unsure how i can do this. e.g.

```
select 
customerid, 
sum(count) as transaction_count,
sum(value) as dollar_amount

from 
cust_orders
```

my table above is at transaction level e.g. transaction_id = 1, 2... etc..I roll it up at customer level but i only want customers who have transacted at least once since November 2019. I don't think it is as simple as adding: 'where yearmonth > 201911'. since e.g. if I have one customer who hasn't transacted since then i don't want any of their aggregated stats above. And if i have had customers who have transacted since november 2019, i do want their transaction counts prior to this included. perhaps i could do:

```
select 
customerid, 
sum(count) as transaction_count,
sum(value) as dollar_amount

from 
cust_orders where customerid in (select 

distinct

customerid 

from cust_orders where yearmonth > 201911))
)
```

**does this make sense?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need aggregation in your first query.  Second, you can use a `HAVING` clause to identify the active customers:

```
select customerid, 
       sum(count) as transaction_count,
       sum(value) as dollar_amount
from cust_orders 
group by customerid
having max(yearmonth) >= 201911;
```

Note:  I interpret "since Nov 2011" as including that month, so I changed the comparison to `>=`.

Comment: so in the count this will still include transations prior to november 2011 since it filters after aggregating? (having clause)

Comment: @Maths12 . . . Exactly.  If you only wanted values since that date in the `sum()`s, you would use `where`.

Comment: thanks, why do you do max(yearmonth) not just yearmonth >= 201911?

Comment: @Maths12 . . . Because it is a `having` clause and any expression with columns that are not in the `group by` needs to use an aggregation function.